# Determine whether each function is one-to-one, onto, or both

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

$g:\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ where $g$ is defined by $g(x)=x-1$

My guess is that this is onto and one-to-one.

But is the correct interpretation of this problem that $g$ is a function of an integer multiplied by another integer?  The integer that is used is derived from the function $g(x)=x-1$?

How should be read?  Sorry if this seems like a silly question.

Comment: Do you really mean $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$? It seems like strange notation.

Comment: If $\Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ is what is written, I think it's a typo and supposed to be $\Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Yes, that is how the question is written

Comment: @Tom that is the notation I'm familiar with from my linear algebra class.  We read that as $\mathbb Z$ is a mapping to $\mathbb Z$

Comment: I do believe it's supposed to be $g : \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}$. The notation $g : \Bbb{Z} \times \Bbb{Z}$ has no meaning that I'm aware of (particularly not in this context), unless for a strange reason the codomain is being suppressed (but in that case $g(x) = x-1$ doesn't really make sense since $x$ would have to be a 2-tuple $x = (a,b)$ where $a, b \in \Bbb{Z}$).

Comment: @Tom Assuming you have the correct notation would you say the function is onto and one-to-one?

Comment: A function from $A$ to $B$ can be identified with a subset of $A\times B$, so perhaps what you mean is that $g\subseteq\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is a function defined by $g(x)=x-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has to be a typo. It should read

> $$g:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z,\quad g(x)=x-1.$$

The notation here means that $g$ is the name of the mapping, the input of $g$ comes from the first set, $\mathbb Z$, the output is in the second set, $\mathbb Z$, and the formula/rule/assignment that is taking place is that $g$ assigns the input, $x$, to the output, $x-1$. Think about it like this
$$
x\overset{g}{\longmapsto} x-1.
$$

As you surmised, this function *is* one-to-one (or "$g$ is an *injection*") [since if $a\not=b$ then $g(a)\not=g(b)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function#Definition) since $a-1\not=b-1$.

$g$ is also onto (or "$g$ is a surjection") [since for every $y\in\mathbb Z$, there is some $x\in\mathbb Z$ such that $g(x)=y$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#Definition). Here, for any integer $y$, we see that $g$ will map the integer $x=y+1$ to that $y$ because $g(x)=g(y+1)=y+1-1=y$.

Since $g$ is both an injection and surjection, we say $g$ is a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection).